Как сохранить в базе данных параметр, если он перезаписывается при получении данных с сервера?
hidden добавлен мной, чтобы скрывать посты для пользователя, не удаляя их на сервере. при declineOrder() значение в БД меняется на 1, но не сохраняется при перезагрузке. Как сохранить это значение в базе данных, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы присвоенный true(1) не становился 0 в базе данных?
Вот остальной код
data class Order(
    @SerializedName("uid")
    val uid: String,
    @SerializedName("a_point")
    val aPoint: String,
    val hidden: Boolean = false,)

 @Entity(tableName = "orders")
data class OrdersEntity (
    @PrimaryKey
    val uid: String,
    val hidden: Boolean,
    val taken: Boolean
    ) {
    fun toDto() = Order(aPoint = aPoint,
    uid = uid,
        hidden = hidden,
        taken = taken)

    companion object {
        fun fromDto(dto: Order) =
            OrdersEntity(
               dto.uid,
                dto.aPoint ?: "",
                dto.hidden
            )
    }
}

fun List<OrdersEntity>.toDto(): List<Order> = map(OrdersEntity::toDto)
fun List<Order>.toEntity(): List<OrdersEntity> = map { OrdersEntity.fromDto(it) } `

    class OrdersRepositoryImpl(
    private val dao: OrdersDao,
) : OrdersRepository {
    override val data = dao.getAll()
        .map(List<OrdersEntity>::toDto)
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)
override suspend fun getAll(){
            try {
                val response = OrdersApiService.service.getAll()
                if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                    throw ApiError(response.code(), response.message())
                }
                val body = response.body() ?: throw ApiError(response.code(), response.message())
                dao.insert(body.toEntity())
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                throw NetworkError
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw UnknownError
            }
    }

    @Dao
interface OrdersDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE hidden = 0 ORDER BY uid DESC")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<OrdersEntity>>

    @Update
    suspend fun update(orders: List<OrdersEntity>)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(orders: List<OrdersEntity>)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(order: OrdersEntity)

    @Query("UPDATE orders SET hidden = 1 WHERE uid = :uid")
    suspend fun hideOrder(uid: String)``` 


получили данные с сервера. проходитесь по массиву, берете его элемент.проверяете есть ли в БД такой элемент по uuid. смотрите на его hidden. копируете это значение в новый ответ из сети. сохраняете в БД.
